# Remnant of a supernova

Tags: acoustics, explosions

i explain better

A supernova remnant  is the structure resulting from the  explosion of a giant star . The supernova remnant is surrounded by an expanding shock wave that is formed from material ejected by the explosion and interstellar material swept  away during the process.

When this material collides with the circumstellar or interstellar gas, forms a shock wave that can heat the gas at high temperatures up to 10 million K, forming a plasma, this is true.

The first question is: exactly what is  the material ejected by the supernova?

other issue is: if we consider for a moment the idea that a "human" might be witnessing the exact moment of the explosion of a supernova, the "superhuman"  would hear the explosion? ie, does  the explosion would  produce some kind of sound?